# Display Next/Prev when looping Custom post-types archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to display the Next/Prev navigation buttons on my page which displays all of the pages within my 'events' custom post-type. The issue is that the buttons are not even displaying, but I have no idea why not. I have had this working with my Blog page posts, but I wonder whether there is something different I need to do with a custom post-type, considering that it's capability is set to 'page' instead of 'post'.

Code:

```
    <?php
    /* Queue the first post, that way we know
     * what date we're dealing with (if that is the case).
     *
     * We reset this later so we can run the loop
     * properly with a call to rewind_posts().
     */
    if ( have_posts() )
        the_post();
?>

<h1>
    <?php _e( 'Results', 'twentyten' ); ?>
</h1>
<div class="resultDetails">
    <p>Displaying all of our Events:</p>
</div>
<ul>
<?php 
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    $paged = ($paged) ? $paged : 1;
?>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'events', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'paged' => $paged ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<li class="resultItem">
    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/thumbs.php?src=<?php echo $image[0]; ?>&w=120&h=120&zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div id="resultText">
        <h2 class="redSubHeader"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endwhile;?>
<nav class="navigation">

    <ul>

        <li class="next-posts post-nav"><?php next_posts_link('Next') ?></li>

        <li class="prev-posts post-nav"><?php previous_posts_link('Prev') ?></li>

    </ul>

</nav>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: After a quick look, i'd say it comes from the "posts_per_page" argument set to -1 which will show all of the posts of one page, therefore restricting the pagination. Try a small number to see what's happening and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` use the global `$wp_query->max_num_pages` to determine if there are more pages. since you're using a new instance of `WP_Query`, the `$wp_query` global does not relate to this new query.

Try explicitly passing `$loop->max_num_pages` to the function:

```
next_posts_link( 'Next' , $loop->max_num_pages );
```

or if you're not using the original query, call `query_posts()` with your arguments instead of creating a new `WP_Query` instance.

**EDIT** - also, as @kevin mentioned, `posts_per_page` set to -1 will load all posts, so you'd have to change that as well for it to paginate.